# Getting keyerror while fetching JSON data from API using python

Tags: python, json, api, keyerror

I am getting `keyerror` in one while printing one of the json data fetched from API using python.

Error:

Except `nagios_service`, I am able to print other data

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-55-3a1eadbbe594>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('Y:/_Temp/MEIPE/python/20190104_Script_Jason_APIv3.py', wdir='Y:/_Temp/MEIPE/python')

  File "C:\Users\MEIPE\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 704, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\MEIPE\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 93, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "Y:/_Temp/MEIPE/python/20190104_Script_Jason_APIv3.py", line 68, in <module>
    print data[i]["_source"]["nagios_service"]

KeyError: 'nagios_service'
```

My code:

```
url1 = "http://nagiosdatagateway.vestas.net/esq/ITE1452552/logstash- 
2018.12.16/2/desc"
response = urllib.urlopen(url1)
data = json.loads(response.read())
#define db connection
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                  "Server=DKCDCVDCP42\DPA;"
                  "Database=VPDC;"
                  "Trusted_Connection=yes;")
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
sql="SELECT count(*)  as count_of_rows FROM [VPDC].[pa]. 
[ROC_Nagios_Reporting_RawData]"
cursor.execute(sql)
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    k = row.count_of_rows
i = 0  
j = len(data)#find length of data set
#print j
for i in range(0,j): #loop to insert date into SQL Server
    print data[i]["_source"]["nagios_service"]
    print data[i]["_source"]["nagios_host"]
    print data[i]["_source"]["nagios_author"]
    print data[i]["_source"]["nagios_severity_label"]
    print data[i]["_source"]["nagios_external_command"]
    print data[i]["_source"]["@timestamp"]
 cnxn.commit() #commit transaction
 cursor.close()
 cnxn.close()
```

I need help in fixing this `keyerror` on `nagios_service`. And should print all data.

Comment: you should print and check value of data[i]["_source"] because their is no key named nagios_service

Comment: Sample data :"_source": {
            "nagios_author": "CHRTO",
            "nagios_external_command": "ADD_SVC_COMMENT",
            "nagios_severity_label": "EXTERNAL COMMAND",
            "nagios_service": "service_Vestas_Park_Regulation_Service",
            "nagios_host": "DE-Albersdorf2-VOB1-SRV",
            "@version": "1",
            "nagios_comment": "start service - 3 - Vestas Park Regulation Service is stopped preparing to start..."
        },
        "sort": [
            1547081581174,
            1547081581174
        ]
    },

Comment: @Maria the fact that ONE of the items has the "nagios_service" key set doesn't mean ALL the items have it.

Comment: is there anyway to include this as an exception, inside my loop? as the actual code is to insert the data into SQL table:                           
   cursor.execute("insert into [VPDC].[pa].[ROC_Nagios_Reporting_RawData] 
   (Nagios_Author,Nagios_host,Nagios_comment) values (?,?, ?)",(data[i] 
   ["_source"]["nagios_author"],data[i]["_source"]["nagios_host"],data[i] 
   ["_source"]["nagios_comment"] ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using try: and except KeyError: in my code after searching SO a little more and was able to insert JSON data into SQL table with out any errors.

```
url1 = "http://nagiosdatagateway.vestas.net/esq/ITE1452552/logstash-" + ysday1
#print url1 #test
#url = "http://nagiosdatagateway.vestas.net/esq/ITE1452552/logstash- 
2018.12.16/2/desc"
response = urllib.urlopen(url1)
data = json.loads(response.read())

#define db connection
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                  "Server=DKCDCVDCP42\DPA;"
                  "Database=VPDC;"
                  "Trusted_Connection=yes;")
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
sql= "SELECT count(*)  as count_of_rows FROM [VPDC].[pa]. 
[ROC_Nagios_Reporting_RawData]"
cursor.execute(sql)
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    k = row.count_of_rows
i = 0  
j = len(data)#find length of data set
#print j

#for each in data:    
for i in range(0,j): #loop to insert date into SQL Server
        try:
            print data[i]["_source"]["nagios_author"]
            print data[i]["_source"]["nagios_service"]
            cursor.execute("insert into [VPDC].[pa].[ROC_Nagios_Reporting_RawData] 
            (Nagios_Author,Nagios_service,Nagios_host,Nagios_comment) values 
            (?,?,?,?)",(data[i]["_source"]["nagios_author"],data[i]["_source"] 
            ["nagios_service"],data[i]["_source"]["nagios_host"],data[i]["_source"] 
            ["nagios_comment"] ))

        except KeyError:
            pass
cnxn.commit() #commit transaction
cursor.close()
cnxn.close() #close connection
```

Answer (score 1):

We might be able to provide a better answer if you showed us the data or explained what the purpose of this was, but for now if you want to run this code without getting exceptions, you need to allow for the possibility that not all the items contain this key. One way would be to use `get()` calls instead of `__getitem__` calls (using square brackets) - the `dict.get(key, default)` method returns `default` if `key` is not in the `dict`, or `None` if you don't provide `default`. So a basic solution would be:

```
for i in range(0,j): #loop to insert date into SQL Server
    source_data = data[i]["_source"]
    print source_data.get("nagios_service")
    print source_data.get("nagios_host")
    print source_data.get("nagios_author")
    print source_data.get("nagios_severity_label")
    print source_data.get("nagios_external_command")
    print source_data.get("@timestamp")
```

A slightly better version that will tell you which key is missing:

```
for i in range(0,j): #loop to insert date into SQL Server
    source_data = data[i]["_source"]
    keys = ['_source', 'nagios_service', 'nagios_host', 'nagios_author',
            'nagios_severity_label', 'nagios_external_command', '@timestamp']
    for key in keys:
        print source_data.get(key, "Missing key: '%s'" % key)
```

Comment: Thank you .. This would help me see the key . won't insert my json data into the sql table. I tried again after some research in SO with the below code